# is there an imagehandler in blogengine.net that will store the images in the database?

Tags: blogengine.net, web-farm

im using blogengine.net in a web farm. I am using sql server to store the data but the images still get loaded into App_Data directory on the webserver. is there an available imagehandler that will store the images in the database?

thanks